# Compiling c++ program with boost header file

Tags: compiling, c++, libraries

I have tried to compile a sample file with a Boost header file in the program as #include .  I have try different options using the -I to include the file name but I get the message that there is no file or directory.  The file is in the directory boost_1_70_1\boost\lambda located in the home folder in Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 0):

When you include any headers files, Those library file should be present in either `/usr/local/include` or `/usr/include` on Linux.

It seems your lib is present in home directory, I would suggest you to run below command and then try to compile your code.

`sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`

Thanks.

Comment: I got the message "E: Unable to locate package boost".  But I was able to download from the Ubuntu archive using:sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev

Comment: @mrcbsbr ohh. i have updated my answer. did it solve your issue?